# Call Flow from Schedulable batch apex

Tags: flow

Can we Call Flow from Schedulable Apex Class. My requirement is to schedule a Flow through apex.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can do this for now. The best we can do now is probably vote on this idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DfnxAAC

**Edit**

Just saw this walkaround in the comments for this idea. Haven't tested it yet but worth a try:

There is actually a work around for this that I am using. Here are the basic steps.

1. Create your triggerable flow
2. Create an Object to use as a "Flow Scheduler" with a check box for the flow you want to run.
3. Create a workflow rule to run your flow when a record is created with that box checked.
4. Use Windows Scheduler to run DataLoader at the scheduled time and have it insert a record into that new Object with the check box set to true.